# antd table pagination bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, antd

I have an issue connected with antd table pagination. I want to make a custom pagination and show 3 items per page at a table. So I am slicing my data into a 3 elements. Everything is ok at a console :) But when I set my array as a `dataSource` prop at first page everything is ok too. After clicking on a second page e.g it's like overriding previous page's data and shows on a second both data. I would be glad to know your opinion what's wrong in this code.

```
<Table
   dataSource={investmentReturnsData.quarter1.data}
   columns={this.investReturnColumns}
   className="c-table c-table-default c-table-dashed hide_head paging_right"
   pagination={{
     pageSize: 3,
     total: investmentReturnsData.quarter1.count,
     onChange: (current) => this.getInvestmentReturnData('quarter1', current),
   }}
/>

const slicedArray = returningData.slice((currentPage - 1) * 3, currentPage * 3);
```

Comment: why are you slicing your data>

Comment: for showing wanted count of data

Comment: It's not working without slicing too. I have tried.

Comment: The two bits of code are completely unconnected. Where does that slicing happen and how do you use the result? Please provide a minimal complete example that can be run by others. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-iikm9?file=/index.js

Comment: Oh, I have already fixed the problem. The problem was connected with key property. They were repeating.